# How to return char * from MASM?

Tags: assembly, dll, c++-cli, masm

I am writing app Caesar Cipher in C++/CLI (GUI and multi-threading) and in MASM(functionality - enciphering and deciphering). I am newbie in assemblers, so i have (propably) simple question, how to return in assembler pointer to char (char *)

C++:

```
char * text;
char * x = CaesarCipherFunctions::start(text);
```

ASM:

```
start proc string: PTR BYTE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By `MOV`ing the address of the string into the `EAX` register (or `RAX` in 64-bit code) before you `RET`.